# Convert Javascript array back into JQuery-type object

Tags: javascript, jquery

For the code below, I wanted to make the _formsOk function work for both Javascript arrays and "JQuery objects". In function1(), I tried to create a Javascript array with all DOM elements except those that have a parent element with id="objectTypesContainer". Basically, function1() filters out the DOM elements I don't want before calling _formsOk() function, which does the actual form validation.

```
function1() {
    var allForms = $('form:not(.vv_hidden)', this.selectMarketsContainer);
    var nonObjectTypeForms = [];
        allForms.each(function () {
            if ($(this).parent().attr("id") !== "objectTypesContainer"){
                nonObjectTypeForms.push($(this)[0]);
            }
        });

        return this._formsOk(nonObjectTypeForms);
},

_formsOk: function($forms) {
        var formOk = true;
        console.log(typeof $forms)
        $forms.each(function () {  // This line fails
            var validator = $(this).validate(DEFAULT_VALIDATION_OPTIONS);
            if (!(validator && validator.form())) {
                formOk = false;
            }
        });
        return formOk;
},
```

However, I realized that because nonObjectTypeForms is now a JS Array rather than a "JQuery Object", the line marked (// This line fails) now fails.

The original code looked like this:

```
function1() {
    var allForms = $('form:not(.vv_hidden)', this.selectMarketsContainer);  // This is a "JQuery object", so no error occurs
    return this._formsOk(allForms);
},

_formsOk: function($forms) {
        var formOk = true;
        console.log(typeof $forms)
        $forms.each(function () {  // This line fails
            var validator = $(this).validate(DEFAULT_VALIDATION_OPTIONS);
            if (!(validator && validator.form())) {
                formOk = false;
            }
        });
        return formOk;
},
```

Is there a way I can convert a JS array into a JQuery object ? I don't want to change _formsOk function definition just yet.

Comment: Doesn't `$forms = $($forms);` works?

Comment: how does it fail?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon. That does work. Thanks for the suggestion. I'm a newbie at Javascript/JQuery.

Comment: @Neil. Some error is returned related to forms object not being JQuery object.

Comment: @JeroenHeier the line is shown in the code - it's `$forms.each()`. It would fail because `$forms` is a plain JS array, so it doesn't have a method called `.each`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of putting all elements in a new array, just use [`.filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) from the jQuery object.

```
allForms.filter(function () {
   return $(this).parent().attr("id") !== "objectTypesContainer")
});
```

This will remove all the items you don't need in your selection and now `allForms` will only have the wanted elements.

Comment: Thank you @VLAZ. That was a much cleaner solution for me!